# Install bootcamp with my parallels partition

Tags: bootcamp, parallels-desktop

I've been using parallels for a while and I want to use that partition for bootcamp. I've read about doing it the other way, using bootcamp in parallels but not from parallels -> bootcamp. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a trivial task - it's easy the other way round, but not this way…

[Converting/Cloning a Parallels VM to Bootcamp on Mac](http://www.tylercrumpton.com/?p=90) has the full details, but this is the précis…

**Process Outline**
These are the basic steps required to get the job done:

1. Create the Boot Camp partition and make it bootable.
2. Copy the source vm’s filesystem to the boot camp partition.
3. Fix the Boot Camp partition’s mount devices and boot manager.
4. Fix the Boot Camp partition’s storage controller drivers and registry values.

**Prerequisites**

- A Mac computer of course.
- Parallels Desktop
- The Windows 7 virtual machine which is to be cloned to the Boot Camp partition. This will be referred to as the “source VM”.
- A second Windows 7 virtual machine which you’ll use to manipulate the source VM and the Boot Camp partition. This will be referred to as the “transfer VM”.
- A Windows 7 install disk.
- Either a Mac OS X install disk or a second Mac that can be connected via a Firewire cable.
- A USB flash drive (of any size).